# How to exclude test cases in release (gTest)

Tags: c++, testing, release, googletest

If I'd use g(oogle)Test, these litte google macros like `FRIEND_TEST(Test, Proc)` are distributed everywhere in my code. Is there  an automatism to exclude them from build, or do I really have to surround those with `#ifdefs`?

Comment: I'd guess a good library would have these `#ifdef`s built in AND that anything by google is good enough in this sense :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything of the sort. `friend` declarations are totally harmless and don't produce any overhead in production code.

Answer (score 0):

You can have friend GTest cases, as mentionned here

[How to make google-test classes friends with my classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396370/how-to-make-google-test-classes-friends-with-my-classes)

As said, there is no overhead to using these macros.

Also, you can work around to test private class members without using `FRIEND_TEST`. One of them is to  write accessors for the tested class' private members in the fixture class, then use the accessors in your tests:

```
class Foo {
  friend class FooTest;
  ...
};

class FooTest : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
  ...
  T1 get_private_member1(Foo* obj) {
    return obj->private_member1_;
  }
};

TEST_F(FooTest, Test1) {
  ...
  get_private_member1(x)
  ...
}
```