# How to access a class's private member through one friend declared class?

Tags: c++, friend-class

I have a struct `Region`, and I want to access its private members in tests like googletest. Now, I have some problems:

1. Some gtests generates dedicated test case class name, so it's hard to declare them as `Region`'s friend.
2. Even though we could, I'm not fond of such friend decls, since friendship doesn't inherit(just like in reality), so I have to write many friend decls for every classes or functions.

There are some ways to mitigate this, however, they are not suitable in my case:

1. Using something like `#ifdef DEBUG ... public: ... #else private:`. We don't do this for some good reasons.
2. Split `Region` into two parts, the new `Region` holds a `RegionImpl`. All tests that needs to access "private" members can test on `RegionImpl`. However, it also has some limitations too.

Now, I want to introduce the current solution of mine, and my question is totally based on this solution. The question is about how to address the drawback of my code. However, feel free to comment if you have a better idea.

The idea is that we can introduce a `DebugRegion` that holds a `Region` inside it, and it's `Region`'s friend. The `DebugRegion` can be viewed as a smart pointer to `Region`, so it can access all `Region`'s public members through `operator->`.

However, when we need to access `Region`'s private members, we have to write a `DEBUG_xxx` to delegate. So we can use `debug_region.DEBUG_foo()` to access.

```
struct Region {
private:
    void foo() {}
    template <typaname T> bool bar(int z);
    static std::string foobar();
private:
    friend DebugRegion;
};

struct DebugRegion
{
    DebugRegion(Region & r)
        : region(r)
    {}
    Region * operator->() { return &region; }
    Region * operator->() const { return &region; }

    void DEBUG_foo() {
        return region.foo();
    }

    template <typaname T> bool DEBUG_bar(int z) {
        return region.bar(z);
    }

    static std::string DEBUG_foobar() {
        return Region::foobar();
    }
private:
    Region & region;
};
```

Now comes my question, in fact, I think create a delegate function for every private members make the solution not perfect. Can we have a "magic" `oeprator->` can even access `Region`'s private members here? I tried, but failed.

By intuition, I think maybe we should have some magic forward function to do so, however I can't come up with that function.

Comment: OT: you better write your code to be testable from the start. If you have to apply tricks and hacks to test your code you are not actually testing what you want to test.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai However, I think it is also quite reasonable that we want to test a private function of a class in unit tests. Meanwhile, there are also some cases that a private member function can be a necessary util function.

Comment: To answer your question, no you can't. That said, why should your tests depend on any internal state of the tested unit? If the state change is not observable, it shouldn't matter. However, I can imagine cases where this isn't convenient, but it's totally unclear what your motivation is and therefore how to approach this better.

Comment: Have you seen the topic on [befriending tests with classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57053790/4885321). But generally what you're doing is likely wrong, because one should test publicly available behaviours, not implementation, as it limits the flexibility of changing implementation details of publicly available APIs.

Comment: @calvin I tend to disagree. If you want to access a private function for testing, then the issue to be fixed is that your code is not testable, not to find a hack to access a private method. Make it public method of some class, create an instance of that class as private member of another class. Now you can test the method, and they are private where they should be private.

Comment: "Meanwhile, there are also some cases that a private member function can be a necessary util function" then make it a separate function/class that's tested separately and held private by its parent class. Then you have best of both worlds.

Comment: tests when done right help with refactoring. Tests that test implementation details achieve the opposite. Anyhow, I placed a bit OT in front of my comment, this is all somewhat opinion based.

Comment: I disagree, testing private functions is not ok. If you want to test "private functions" then these functions should be available for test in isolation. The pimpl pattern can help here too. You can have an inner class NOT visible to the end user that will have all methods public which is fully testable.

Comment: I think there are reasonable cases where you organize code in hierarchies/modules, where private access means private to the level of hierarchy/same module. This is so common, in fact, that many languages specifically have features to facilitate this organization. I don't know if it's a good idea, but I have written a [library](https://github.com/Sinacam/memptr) that breaks access control, which might do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ideal, but it does not require to add a `DebugRegion` type. Your "magic `operator->`" cannot be done, as far as I can tell, because friendship is not transferable.

You can add a function template to your class-to-be-tested but not implement it:

```
struct Region {
private:
    void foo() {}
    template <typaname T> bool bar(int z);
    static std::string foobar();
public:
    template <typename> void testRegion(); // you may want to make this const
};
```

Then in your gtest or whatever framework you use, you implement one `testRegion` for each individual test. You can even use the class name of your current test-instance, but I'll keep the example simple:

```
// in RegionTest.cpp or similar
namespace {
  struct tagRegionTestFoo {};
  struct tagRegionTestBar {};
}

template <>
void Region::testRegion<tagRegionTestFoo>() {
  // your test impl for test "foo" with private access
}

TEST(Region, foo) {
  Region region{};
  // public manipulation of region
  region.testRegion<tagRegionTestFoo>();
}

template <>
void Region::testRegion<tagRegionTestBar>() {
  // your test impl for test "bar" with private access
}

TEST(Region, bar) {
  Region region{};
  // public manipulation of region for test "bar"
  region.testRegion<tagRegionTestBar>();
}
```

You can instantiate this for as many individual tests as you like. Of course `testRegion` could also be a `friend` or `static` if you prefer. This *can* be misused, but only knowingly.

Comment: I think this way can apply to my scene. All I have to do is to make the testRegion to accept a closure